# Remove Oracle Apex Interactive Grid row actions

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX, how do I remove different actions in the interactive grid row actions?

I'd like to remove the ability to delete or add rows from both the row actions and selection actions menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Region Settings, Advanced, Static ID: `emp`

Page Settings, JavaScript, Execute when Page Loads

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var actions = apex.region("emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions");
    actions.remove("selection-add-row");
    actions.remove("selection-duplicate");
    actions.remove("selection-fill"); 
    actions.remove("selection-clear"); 
    actions.remove("selection-delete");
    actions.remove("selection-copy-down");
    actions.remove("selection-copy");
    actions.remove("selection-refresh"); 
    actions.remove("selection-revert"); 
    actions.remove("single-row-view");
    actions.remove("row-add-row");
    actions.remove("row-duplicate");
    actions.remove("row-delete"); 
    actions.remove("row-refresh"); 
    actions.remove("row-revert"); 
});
```

You can change "emp" to anything you'd like, change in both the static ID and javascript. Delete the lines you'd like to keep.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `actions.hide("{action_id}")` and `actions.show("{action_id}")` to hide and show the row actions.