# Remove actions from the Interactive Grid "Row Action" button - Oracle Apex v21.1

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I would like to remove the Single Row View action on the "Row Actions" button on the Interactive Grid :

[image: Single Row View]

Also, I would like to remove these following actions on the row actions menu aswell, because these have no translations available based on the [translation documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/translating-messages.html#GUID-ED453806-E775-445C-A73C-6CAFD2359A93) for the 21.1 version of Oracle Apex :

[image: row actions to remove]

I came across some existing post about this subject, but I don't know why it's not working for me, I tried to add a static ID to the IG and put this JavaScript function on Page Load (credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801228/remove-oracle-apex-interactive-grid-row-actions)) :

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var actions = apex.region("archiveList").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions");
    actions.remove("selection-add-row");
    actions.remove("selection-duplicate");
    actions.remove("selection-fill"); 
    actions.remove("selection-clear"); 
    actions.remove("selection-delete");
    actions.remove("selection-copy-down");
    actions.remove("selection-copy");
    actions.remove("selection-refresh"); 
    actions.remove("selection-revert"); 
    actions.remove("single-row-view");
    actions.remove("row-add-row");
    actions.remove("row-duplicate");
    actions.remove("row-delete"); 
    actions.remove("row-refresh"); 
    actions.remove("row-revert"); 
});
```

To summarize everything, I want to remove these following actions :

- Single Row View
- Copy to Clipboard
- Copy Down
- Fill
- Clear

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me (on 21.2). I created a dynamic action on page load with a true action of type "execute javascript". My region static id is "emp-ig".

```
let actions = apex.region("emp-ig").call("getActions");
actions.hide("selection-duplicate");
actions.hide("selection-delete");
actions.hide("selection-copy-down");
actions.hide("selection-copy");
actions.hide("selection-refresh"); 
actions.hide("selection-revert"); 
actions.hide("selection-add-row");
actions.hide("selection-fill"); 
actions.hide("selection-clear"); 
actions.hide("single-row-view");
actions.hide("row-add-row");
actions.hide("row-duplicate");
actions.hide("row-delete"); 
actions.hide("row-refresh");  
actions.hide("row-revert");
```

The `actions.remove` doesn't work for all actions, and it also throws warnings in the console. Since you're removing all actions from the row actions menu I'd hide that column from the report.

Comment: Sweet ! Thanks ! I just added it as "Execute When Page Loads" on the Page attributes instead of a DA, but your solution helped me a lot ! Thanks :-D